# why is d3 each() function only iterating through first item in list?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

For some reason, when I implement the d3 each() function it only acts upon the first item in an array.  For example, in the following function, only the user ID of the first user in the array is alerted:

https://jsbin.com/hayedeh/edit?html,js

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can do `forEach` like this:

```
  users.forEach(function(user)
  {
    alert(user.userID);
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `selectAll` instead of `select` will iterate the entire array.  That said, you need to read up on [selections](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Selections.md#d3_selectAll).  This is an odd use case (selecting an array).  It's meant to be used with selectors or node elements to traverse collections of **DOM elements**.  I see little need to use it to traverse regular arrays.  Just use good old fashioned array methods.